# Cloudflare Timeout Issue with Git pull and Curl Request in AWS EC2 instance

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, timeout, cloudflare

I have my WordPress project running in the AWS EC2 instance. I have my DNS managed in Cloudflare and it is proxied. When I did the setup of the project in AWS instance, for some days git pull and push and all the APIs were working fine. But suddenly after some time, I was not able to take the pull on the server due to a timeout issue.

Also from the WordPress form when I submit the form it should call the API but it gives me the 504 gateway timeout error.

So every time when I need to take a pull I have to reboot the server and then for 5 mins. everything works fine and then again it gives me the same error.

What should I do with Cloudflare? As per my knowledge, there must be something from Cloudflare as on the server-side I have tried everything for this kind of problem.